Signing multiple transfers using the CLI and submitting them in bulk via HTTP RPC
I'm working on a feature in my app where the user will sign two transfers and then broadcast them in one transaction. I'm a little confused in the steps, and just to clarify we are not using the web3 javascript SDK, and instead need to handle this using the Solana CLI and RPC endpoints.

Signing the transactions.

To start, we sign the two transfers:
# Transfer 1
solana transfer --sign-only --output json --blockhash 84Dsd5FuDwqF2G89hWAyvK8EArnqXXXXXX --fee-payer .gas-station-keypair XXXXXXXXXXXXXXBGFVomiSuqKpLbjrEFcnS 1
=> {
  "blockhash": "84Dsd5FuDwqF2G89hWAyvK8EArnqxkCGwDUcXfLCFJgU",
  "signers": [ "CfyCCJNEC8HGDoWLBcBfcWCQbrcN6Q8ds6z3nUhMa168=4R92sqE2BrwrypR7fCmR6tDRt4e42rBs64vFtWRoseBQha64G5a2Sz6uMjugUrERapeSEYZTfNGDVCL83PsWkCn7",
"FHLdZELUCWFyVngLoJoCZhw5QiMm2LeibaLpmiDUAYsp=58LWtzqfgt6qcyAKAe6idTXXU8HCKA69mpnqVbqYEwbBk8njuLCDvwBm8yFw95RjbKjxFLPx4Bhj2ZRuoEgXWnaw"
  ]
}

# Transfer 2
solana transfer --sign-only --output json --blockhash 84Dsd5FuDwqF2G89hWAyvK8EArnqXXXXXX --fee-payer .gas-station-keypair YYYYYYYYYYYBGFVomiSuqKpLbjrEFcnS 0.1
=> {
  "blockhash": "84Dsd5FuDwqF2G89hWAyvK8EArnqxkCGwDUcXfLCFJgU",
  "signers": [ "CHCHCHCHCHCHCHHGDoWLBcBfcWCQbrcN6Q8ds6z3nUhMa168=4R92sqE2BrwrypR7fCmR6tDRt4e42rBs64vFtWRoseBQha64G5a2Sz6uMjugUrERapeSEYZTfNGDVCL83PsWkCn7",
"CHPEPEPEPEPEPw5QiMm2LeibaLpmiDUAYsp=58LWtzqfgt6qcyAKAe6idTXXU8HCKA69mpnqVbqYEwbBk8njuLCDvwBm8yFw95RjbKjxFLPx4Bhj2ZRuoEgXWnaw"
  ]
}

Now with both transfers signed by all parties, I want to broadcast them both as one transaction.

Broadcasting the Transaction

curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "sendTransaction",
    "params": [
      <WHAT_GOES_HERE>
    ]
  }
'

I'm unclear on how to properly format (combine) the previously signed transactions before base64 encoding them.
--------------UPDATE---------------
I'm using this script to combine two serialized messages and then submit them to the RPC sendTransaction endpoint. However, while there are no errors they transfers also never happen.
#!/bin/bash

# Replace with your RPC endpoint
RPC_URL="http://127.0.0.1:8899"

# Load your keypair
KEYPAIR=~/keypairs/whale1

# Receiver's public keys (replace with actual receiver addresses)
RECEIVER_PUBKEY_1=$(solana address -k ./rand1) 
RECEIVER_PUBKEY_2=$(solana address -k ./rand2)

echo "Starting balance for receiver 1: $(solana balance $RECEIVER_PUBKEY_1)"
echo "Starting balance for receiver 2: $(solana balance $RECEIVER_PUBKEY_2)"
echo "Starting balance for sender: $(solana balance $KEYPAIR)"

# Amount to send in SOL for each receiver
AMOUNT_1="0.1"
AMOUNT_2="0.2"

# Get the recent blockhash
BLOCKHASH=$(solana block | grep 'Recent Blockhash:' | awk '{print $3}')

TX_FILE=~/keypairs/solana_multi_tx.json

# Create the first transfer instruction and sign it
solana transfer $RECEIVER_PUBKEY_1 $AMOUNT_1 --from $KEYPAIR --blockhash $BLOCKHASH --sign-only --allow-unfunded-recipient --dump-transaction-message --output json > $TX_FILE
# Create the second transfer instruction and sign it
solana transfer $RECEIVER_PUBKEY_2 $AMOUNT_2 --from $KEYPAIR --blockhash $BLOCKHASH --sign-only --allow-unfunded-recipient --dump-transaction-message --output json  | jq '.message' > tx2.json

# Combine transactions into one
TX_COMBINED=$(jq -s '.[0].message + .[1]' $TX_FILE tx2.json)

# Prepare the signed transaction
SIGNED_TX=$(echo $TX_COMBINED | base64)
SIGNATURE=$(cat $TX_FILE | jq -r '.signers[0]')

# Example command to send one of the transactions, as combining them is complex:

# Get response from the RPC endpoint
RESULT=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "sendTransaction",
  "params": [
    "'$SIGNED_TX'",
    {"encoding": "base64" }
  ]
}' $RPC_URL)

sleep 3

echo "Ending balance for receiver 1: $(solana balance $RECEIVER_PUBKEY_1)"
echo "Ending balance for receiver 2: $(solana balance $RECEIVER_PUBKEY_2)"
echo "Ending balance for sender: $(solana balance $KEYPAIR)"

This is still related to my original post, as it's the steps needed to be completed to broadcast 2 or more signed transfers in one request.
Can anyone please help me understand what I'm missing?

tldr you won't be able to do this with the current strategy
On Solana, transactions are made of instructions, which are then compiled to a "message". The private key signs the message bytes with a blockhash, the signature is added to the transaction, and then the whole thing is serialized and sent off.
In your case, you've created two different messages, signed them individually, and then concatenated the two, along with their signatures. When the validator receives this transaction, it will simply fail to deserialize the message, since they're just concatenated. On top of that, it will fail to verify the signatures, since the signatures don't concern the full transaction payload.
Unfortunately, it won't be possible to do this with the CLI -- you'll need to write code to create one transaction that contains two instructions (the two transfers), and then sign and send that off. The transaction would look something like:
use solana_rpc_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_sdk::transaction::Transaction;
use solana_sdk::system_instruction;

// stuff here...

     let payer = // YOUR KEYPAIR HERE
     let client = RpcClient::new("<ENDPOINT_HERE>");
     let transfer1_instr = system_instruction::transfer(
         &payer.pubkey(),
         &receiver1_pubkey,
         amount1,
     );
     let transfer2_instr = system_instruction::transfer(
         &payer.pubkey(),
         &receiver2_pubkey,
         amount2,
     );

     let blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash()?;
     let tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
         &[transfer1_instr, transfer2_instr],
         Some(&payer.pubkey()),
         &[payer],
         blockhash,
     );

     let _sig = client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&tx)?;

Note that I didn't try to compile this, but I just lifted it from https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/485216bd77752621be14553fccc27b4e38c7c41f/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L518

Thanks so much for the response Jon! Makes sense and I appreciate you taking the time.
